# How can I run a headless AI server with k80 TPU? I still want to run X11 programs on an X server or Wayland

Tags: linux, gpu, headless

-1

I set up a system with a 1050 ti gpu and a k80 tpu. It works fine. When I remove the 1050 ti, I can't ssh into this system. I think the system isn't booting. Because I'm trying to run headless, I can't see any system error messages. Booting with the 1050 ti means I can only use one cuda device on my k80. Certain parallel operations fail because of 1050 is not homogeneous with the k80 -- even though I set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES. I'd appreciate any ideas. I'm willing to run any version of linux on this machine. It's a Ryzen 3600 on an x570 with a custom cooling solution. I may try removing gdm before installing a server version of an OS, if either makes any sense. Thank you

Comment: Have you considered using a cheap radeon GPU for X11 instead of the 1050?  it's not nvidia, so it can't be detected as a potential CUDA device.   Note that sometime this year, AMD are about to release 5000 G series APUs with built-in GPUs and with anywhere from 4 to 8 CPU cores and 6, 7, or 8 GPU compute units, so you can have radeon graphics without using a PCI-e slot.   (unfortunately, now is a terrible time to be buying any CPU or GPU, even old, slow GPUs are over-priced and hard to find)

Comment: Alternatively, run your CUDA app in a VM and configure the system so that the k80 is passed through to the VM.

Comment: Good ideas.  Thanks!

Comment: If any of those ideas work, please write up what you did as an answer, and then Accept it (unless someone else does it, or comes up with a better answer)

Comment: I ordered a cheap amd card with 1GB of vram for $20.  I'll let you know if that does the trick when it's delivered.  I'll try the other too.  I'm curous about which is the optimal solution.